# Unreadable font using iTextSharp PRTokeniser

Tags: itext

I need to do a low level text extraction using PRTokeniser

For some PDF files everything is fine but for some others I get empty strings (or rather a string made up by empty boxes or empty characters).

All such files follow this pattern:

```
endobj
7 0 obj
<</BaseFont/RDZRPI+TimesNewRoman/FontDescriptor 8 0 R/Type/Font
/FirstChar 1/LastChar 10/Widths[ 444 500 444 500 444 333 500 500 278 250]
/Encoding 11 0 R/Subtype/TrueType>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Type/Encoding/BaseEncoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Differences[
1/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/space]>>
endobj
```

Each character in the token stringvalue is not an ASCII or ANSI code but the index of the differences array. For instance if I have a string like "abc" I would get 1,2,3. Then iTextSharp would understand such codes as ASCII codes and would render them like empty square boxes or any other character.

Therefore I would need to get the subset array: number 1 is "a", number 2 is "b"...

The problem is that the basefont.differences array has only empty values and therefore I don't know how to rebuild the string.

On the other hand strategy.GetResultantText rendes the page content properly, but I need much more detail and that’s way I'm using PRTokeniser, although I'm stuck with this font problem.

Any ideas?

---

The PDF streams are all like this:

```
/FirstChar 1/LastChar 8/Widths[ 722 444 278 500 250 944 333 500]
/Encoding 11 0 R/Subtype/TrueType>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Type/Encoding/BaseEncoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Differences[
1/H/e/l/o/space/W/r/d]>>
```

In this case there is only this sentence in the PDF: Hellow Word. Therefore the chars array would be:

```
1 H
2 e
3 l
4 o
5 space
6 W
7 r
8 d
```

I need to find such an array using iTextSharp in order to decipher the string tokens.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mark for your answer:

You are awfully right. Therefore, I tried to peek under the covers at what strategy.GetResultantText as you suggested me to do,  without much success. My final goal is to get each word coordinates in a pdf file. Therefore, I gave a try to the LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy, which seems a reasonably starting point.

I can get the text rendered nicely, but I don’t know how to get the coordinates of each word or chunk. I would need to get access to something like the locationalResult array ( if such an array exists), but I don't know how.

Here is my code (VB.net):

```
Public Sub ParseLocation(ByVal sourcePDF As String)
    Dim reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sourcePDF)
    Dim parser As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser(reader)
    Dim strategy As parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy
    Dim sResult As String

    For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages
        strategy = parser.ProcessContent(i, New LocationTextExtractionStrategy)
        sResult = strategy.GetResultantText
        Debug.Print(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy))
        Debug.Print(sResult)

        strategy = parser.ProcessContent(i, New LocationTextExtractionStrategy)
        Debug.Print(strategy.GetResultantText())
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is also not an answer (see my comment to your additional "answer" posted as @user584106 to this question), despite the upvote you got for it. Please read my comment to the other "answer". I'm not downvoting this because of your new status here at SO, but you should get more familiar with the operation of this site before you start losing reputation. :)

Answer (score 0):

`11 0 obj <>` isn't even valid PDF syntax... (or is it?)  An empty dictionary looks like `<<>>`.  I suspect you're missing a detail or two.

An encoding entry must be a dictionary or a string.  Erk!  <> is a valid empty String.  Such strings are bytes encoded as hex values... <0102030304050604070308> -> "Hello World" in your sample encoding.

OTOH, an encoding entry may only be a name or dictionary (PdfName or PdfDictionary in iText-speak), so even if that really is an empty hex string, its still invalid.

At this point, I think you can cheerfully embrace Open Source and take a peek under the covers at what `strategy.GetResultantText` is doing.

PS: I think you're overusing PRTokenizer.  Using on the stream portion of a content stream is fine and dandy, but using it to re-parse dictionaries and such is pure overhead.  Those objects have already been parsed and turned into instances of `PdfStream`, `PdfString`, `PdfDictionary`, and so forth... using `PRTokenizer`.

```
PdfDictionary fontDict = magicallyFindFontDict();
PdfObject encodingObj = fontDict.getAsDirectObject(PdfName.ENCODING);
if (encodingObj == null) { //bail
} else if (encodingObj.isName()) {
  if (PdfName.WINANSIENCODING.equals(encodingObj)) {
    ...
  } else if (...) {}...

} else if (encodingObj.isDictionary()) {
  // details in 9.6.6 of ISO PDF Spec
  ...
}
```